# How can I test my calculator using npm test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, jestjs

I have a simple calculator web project: https://github.com/DANIILNEDOSTUP/js-calculator

I want to do simple tests (addition and subtraction for example) using **npm** + **jest**.
I created **package.json** and wrote these lines:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

then created **script.test.js** file and wrote lines:

```
const add = require('./script');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

then I call a **npm test** command from terminal (I use Ubuntu 20.04)

Then I see a mistake:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

and complains about 131 lines of code

```
clearKey.addEventLisener('click', clearEquation);
```

Is it realistic to do a test?
I want to make CI / CD for this application, I don't really understand JavaScript.

Comment: Can you show the contents of ./script (or atleast the lines around the error)? Likely what's happening here is you are adding an event listener in the global scope of that script which would make it run as soon as it is imported into your test.   If that is indeed the case, you should wrap your initialization functionality in a function and call it directly from your entrypoint.

Comment: yes, you would need to organise your code so you don't fire UI events, why would an add function have an event listener?

Comment: In order to test your code, you need to first write a `testable` code, You need to re-organize your code.

Comment: This is not modular code but some browser script. Jest wasn't made for this. Rewrite it or do e2e tests, i.e. load the script with <script> in html as it would be done in prod and assert its effects on DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I can see is that your code is not even exporting anything. You have everything in 1 single file `script.js` and that is not a good practice, testable code will be annoying; however, is okay for now. To solve your issue, your script should export the `add` method.

Something like this should work.

At the end of `scripts.js` write something like this

```
module.exports = { add }
```

then in your test

```
const { add } = require('./script');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

**EDIT**

This will not work in a web browser as mentioned in the comments.

However, one hack I can think of is checking if module.exports exists. So adding to `scripts.js` the following code should "fix it"

```
if (typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = { add }
}
```

Another solution I can think about is move all of your test code to `scripts.js` which is also not a good idea (it is a really bad idea actually) and it won't solve your specific issue because you are requiring dom support.

**EDIT 2**
As mentioned in the comments, DOMS are not supported in `node.js` and the fact you are calling a test script which requires a module that tries to run the whole file which fails when it gets to the DOM part, so to better fix your issue you really need to break down your code into modules.

Additionally, we can and will use webpack in our case. This would be almost impossible (at least for me) task to do without the use of webpack. Also I highly suggest you learn `webpack` as it is very important in what you are trying to do.

Without further ado, here is your folder structure

- | dist (this folder is auto generated by webpack)
- | src

  - | arithmetics.js
  - | scripts.js
  - | index.html
  - | stlye.css
- | package.json
- | webpack.config.js
- | test.js

and everything else you have, obviously it can be broken down much much more and create better code but I am trying to keep it simple here and not over complicate your logic.

**Disclaimer: I am not a webpack pro at all, I am a backend engineer not frontend so whatever I am referencing in webpack here can be written much better than what I am doing**

**arithmetics.js**

```
const add = (a, b) => +a + +b;
const substract = (a, b) => +a - +b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => (b == '0' ? 'Err' : roundResult(a / b));
const roundResult = (n) => Math.round((n + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100; // Rounds n to 2 decimal places

module.exports = {
      add,
      subtract,
      multiply,
      divide,
      roundResult
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
/* Math operations */
let equation = '0';
let previousEquation = '0';
let previousOperator = '';

const {add, substract, multiply, divide, roundResult} = require('./arithmetics');

const operate = (operator, a, b = a) => {
...
```

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
   ...
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
    "test": "jest",
   ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
 }
...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/scripts.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Webpack Output",
    }),
  ],
};
```

**test.js**

```
const { add } = require('./src/arithmetics');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Note: Any file I didn't include its code then it should be untouched

Note2: Make sure to run `npm install` or `yarn` to install packages!

Now run `npm run build`, a new folder named `dist` should be generated. Copy from src `index.html`, `style.css` and from dist copy `scripts.js` and that should be what you upload to your server (this step can be automated so that dist will include your entire code base, but again I dont know webpack that well)

to test your code you can simply run `npm test`

The above code works 100% fine on my local machine.

Comment: And it will start throwing an error in a browser because there's no `module`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I tested and the error persists((

Comment: Of course it would in a web browser. The question though is asking about unit tests using jest. I just noticed the html part. My apologies.

Comment: @DaniilNedostup Check my edited answer and let me know if that might work. Assuming your running something like `npm test` in your console

Comment: @MuhandJumah Applied the changes, but nothing changed ...

Comment: Here is your issue, the above code works 100%. I tested it on my local machine, but your problem is everything is in 1 single big file. Your script is defining DOM elements which are not present in node.js. DOM are only available in a web browser. To best fix your code you would need divide your code into sub modules. I will update my answer to include such break down.

Comment: @DaniilNedostup please see my updated answer under `EDIT 2`. Good luck with the rest.

Comment: @MuhandJumah YES! IT WORKING! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!! ;)

Comment: Not a problem, my pleasure!